# import the data to db in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have sql data in .sql format. and I need to import it to the MySql database. What are all the steps should I take.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? This process is documented quite a bit, a google search should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.sql` file only contains a lot of SQL queries.

The simplest way to import your file is to execute those SQL queries, with the [**`mysql` command-line tool**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) :

```
mysql --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --host=HOST DB_NAME < your_sql_file.sql
```

This will send all the content of `your_sql_file.sql` to the `mysql` program, which will execute it -- and, so, import your data.

Of course, you'll have to replace the upper-case `USER`, `PASSWORD`, `HOST`, and `DB_NAME` with your real connection informations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any software to connect with mysql? If yes, then there should be opion for importing data. Try that.

Comment: which software i can use to connect

Comment: There are lot of free GUI Tools for MySQL. Try any free fromhttp://www.mustap.com/databasezone_post_148_top-10-free-mysql-tools